# What is the difference between @include breakpoint and @include at-breakpoint?

Tags: sass, susy-compass, compass-sass

I have a question because I am working on a project where my team is using @include breakpoint and @include at-breakpoint. We are using sass, compass, and susy. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Did you try looking at the source for those mixins?

Comment: I found the source for at-breakpoint but not breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at-breakpoint` is part of Susy, and is used for changing your total column-count at different breakpoints. Inspired by that initial syntax, [Mason Wendell](http://thecodingdesigner.com/) created a more powerful and generic [Breakpoint Plugin](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) for managing all your media-queries. Now, many people (including me) use both in the same project. They work great together, but the differences can be confusing.

- Use `at-breakpoint` when you want to change your susy `$total-columns` setting based on a min/max width media-query.
- Use `breakpoint` for more complex media-queries, or anywhere you don't want to change the number of columns.

If you want to use only one of them, and be more consistent, you can recreate the functionality of `at-breakpoint` using the longhand:

```
@include breakpoint($media-query) { // set your media-query
  @include layout($columns) { // set your columns
    // nested code will use the new column count at the given media-query
  }
}
```

`at-breakpoint` is simply a shortcut for that.